# Using Python and Pandas I'm writing a function to query a string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**How it works**

My script does this, it takes a string as an argument, and then performs a search in a Pandas dataframe. My initial code was too repetitive so I decided to write a function to avoid this repetition. My code was

```
    import pandas as pd
    

    df = pd.read_csv('messages.csv')`
    ln = df[['FROM','TO','CONTENT']]
    # ln = ln.loc['mystring'] template
    # 
    
    terms = ln.loc[(ln['TO'] == 'Steve Warren') & (ln['FROM'] != 'Kevin Jones') &  (ln['FROM'] == 'LinkedIn Member')]
    
    # Additional data manipulation to
    # Drop NA and NaN from the results
    ln.dropna(inplace=True)
    # New subsets after data mining
    # My formulae
    terms1 = ln[ln.CONTENT.str.contains('word1')]
    terms2 = ln[ln.CONTENT.str.contains('word2|word3')]
    terms3 = ln[ln.CONTENT.str.contains('word4')]
    terms4 = ln[ln.CONTENT.str.contains('word5')]
    terms5 = ln[ln.CONTENT.str.contains('word6')]
    terms6 = ln[ln.CONTENT.str.contains('word7')]
    terms7 = ln.loc[(ln['TO'] == 'John Patrick') & (ln['FROM'] !=
                                  'Jared Rohm') & (ln['FROM'] ==
                                     'Young Yang') | ['CONTENT'] =='company name']
```

This mess works as is, but it can be improved, and when was working on a solution to improve it, I decided to write a function to avoid repetition:

```
    def searchTerm(term, **kwargs):
       '''
       Looks for the desired term/terms in the dataframe.
       '''
       df = pd.read_csv('messages.csv')
       ln = ln = df[['FROM','TO','CONTENT']]
       terms = ln[ln.CONTENT.str.contains(term)]
       return terms
```

From the above, you can see, I was experimenting with **kwargs to pass the remaining templates, somehow, as I am not sure, got stuck there, if its better to write a general function that accepts any number of parameters, or create separate ones for each case ...
Kind of stuck there, I know for the most simple case, it doesn't need the second argument **kwargs, but I was wondering if for more complex cases it can be used, or what to use instead.

Comment: What do you envision the remaining **kwargs to be used for?

Comment: @D. Rooij  Thanks for the question, I thought I answered this yesterday, but apparently it didn't go through ... I refreshed the screen and lost it.
ok, here's the answer again to why I used **kwargs, it was most like a placeholder to remind me I wasn't finish with this function, for the more complex cases, as **kwargs take many arguments, I thought I could write a template and use it, my knowledge of case uses of **kwargs is at beginner level, that's why I asked here for help or guidance on the more complex function definition. I do understand the logic of writing the function but that's it.